# Extjs - Setvalue to numberfield inside combo

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a window like **http://jsfiddle.net/FZfCC/**

[image]

I want to setValue(myvalue) to field **a2** in function of combobox (**a1**) like

```
            listeners: {
                render: function(combo) {
                     Ext.getCmp('a2').setValue(0); // not working
                }
            }
```

But that not working. How can i fix that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use beforeRender

```
            beforeRender: function(combo) {
                 Ext.getCmp('a2').setValue(0);
            }
```

Now it's should be working.